# How to get an image size?

Tags: c#, image

How can I get a specific image size in a console application (Not a form application)?
Most answers I have found are using System.Drawing which does not work on a Console Application...

Comment: why do you thing System.Drawing doesn't work in Console application?

Comment: Have you tried adding the System.Drawing assembly to your console application?

Comment: `System.Drawing` works fine as long as it's referenced

Answer (score 4):

Add the reference System.Drawing by right clicking on your project, then add reference. Then you can add `using System.Drawing;` as with any other reference in the entire of .NET.

You can then use the Image class

```
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("filePath");
Int32 w = image.Width;
Int32 h = image.Height;
```

Comment: Strange... why have my comments disappeared?